# Can you make a product of kernels?

Tags: integral-transforms

Let's apply two integral transforms to a function $f(t)$.

$$ F'(v) = \int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2} K_1(t,v) f(t) \mathrm{d}t $$

$$ F(u) = \int\limits_{v_1}^{v_2} K_2(v,u) F'(v) \mathrm{d}v $$

Can I construct a kernel $K(t,u)$ that would replace the two? Like this:

$$ F(u) = \int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2} K(t,u) f(t) \mathrm{d}t $$

I attempted to simply insert it and it seems that it's nearly possible:

$$ F(u) = \int\limits_{v_1}^{v_2} K_2(v,u) \int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2} K_1(t,v) f(t) \mathrm{d}t \, \mathrm{d}v $$

$$ F(u) =  \int\limits_{v_1}^{v_2} \int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2} K_1(t,v) K_2(v,u) f(t)\mathrm{d}t \, \mathrm{d}v $$

So I am tempted to say that

$$ K(t,u) = \int\limits_{v_1}^{v_2} K_1(t,v) K_2(v,u) \mathrm{d}v $$

But is that legitimate? Can I change the order of integration that freely here? Usually we have to reconsider the limits of integrations when swapping the order...

I am asking this because I am interested in kernels as of continuous analog of matrices and this "kernel product" would seem to be the analog of matrix multiplication.

Comment: what is your definition of a Kernel?

Comment: By kernel I mean the function $K(t,u)$ that is used in an integral transform. When we apply an integral transform to function $f(t)$, we integrate the function multiplied by some other stuff. That other stuff (all of it together) I consider to be the kernel. And here I am asking if it is possible to define a general way to get a kernel product $K=K_1 \times K_2$ that would produce the same transform as transforms with $K_1$ and $K_2$ used one after another.